# how to return this into an array or list of double

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream, flatmap

I cannot manage to retrieve this into an array or a collection, how am i supposed to do it ?

```
Stream<double[]> pyt = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
            .boxed().flatMap(a->IntStream.rangeClosed(a, 100)
                    .mapToObj(b->new double[]{a,b,Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b)})
                    .filter(t->t[2]%1==0));
```

this doesn't work

```
double[] arr = (double[])pyt.toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly do you want to achieve. Currently you have a stream of `double[]` arrays. If you want to collect them into `double[][]` array, you need to write:

```
double[][] arr = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
                .boxed()
                .flatMap(a->IntStream.rangeClosed(a, 100)
                .mapToObj(b->new double[]{a,b,Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b)})
                .filter(t->t[2]%1==0))
                .toArray(double[][]::new);
```

If you want to flatten it to `double[]` array, you need to write

```
double[] arr = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
                .boxed()
                .flatMap(a->IntStream.rangeClosed(a, 100)
                .mapToObj(b->new double[]{a,b,Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b)})
                .filter(t->t[2]%1==0))
                .flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream)
                .toArray();
```